# quiz score variable isnt updating after quiz is completed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, local-storage

I am making a JS quiz app and have all the functionality down except for one thing. When the user is done taking the quiz the most recent score doesn't update and will just keep displaying the first score given. This impacts the ability to display the correct score to the user and also prevents a new score being added to the leaderboard. Its a pretty big project with multiple files. So there is a lot to paste into stack.

I want to give a layout of the file structure to make it as easy to understand as possible:

The user starts at the home page which consists of **index.html**, **style.css** and **script.js**. To the user This is the choice of two buttons a play button and a high scores button.

The play button goes to **game.html**, **game.css** and still utilizes **script.js** and this is the file where the game takes place.

The highscores button utilizes **highscores.html**, **highscores.css**, and **highscores.js**. This page uses js dom manipulation to add highscores from local storage to put them in a list for the user to see and come back too.

The end page is what the user is presented with after the quiz is finished. this is where the user is prompted to input their name to save the score they just received and then save it to the leaderboard. This page utilize the **end.html**, **style.css**, and **end.js**.

I believe the problem lies with in the communication of the **highscores.js/html** or the **end.js/html** So Ill give those four files on here and please feel free to ask for others in need be. But I really appreciate the help!

In order to get a highscore you will have to go through the quiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>JavaScript Quiz Project</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div id="home" class="flex-column flex-center">
           <h1>Good Luck!</h1>
           <a href="./game.html" class="btn">Play</a>
           <a href="./highscores.html" class="btn" id="highscores-btn">Highscores</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="./assets/script.js"></script>
```

Here is the HTML for the game page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Good Luck!</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center">
            <div id="hud">
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <!-- container desc -->
                    <p id="container-text" class="hud-prefix">
                        Question:
                    </p>
                    <!-- timer function -->
                    <div id="timer">
                        <h1 id="time-text">90</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of timer -->
                </div>
                <div class="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score:
                    </p>
                <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                    0
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="question">*question section placeholder*</h1>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/script.js"></script>
```

The js for the home screen and game screen

```
const question = document.getElementById('question');
const choices = Array.from($('.choice-text'));
const scoreText = document.getElementById('score');

//defining let var which values will change throughout the game
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQustions = [];

//defining list of potential questions to be called apon by currentQuestions
let questions = [
    {
        question: 'What types of variables can you define?',
        choice1: 'var',
        choice2: 'let',
        choice3: 'const',
        choice4: 'all of the above',
        answer: '4'
    },
    // question 1 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How would you store an item to local storage?',
        choice1: 'localStorage.getItem()',
        choice2: 'localStorage.setItem()',
        choice3: 'localStorage.store()',
        choice4: 'localStorage.setLocal()',
        answer: '2'
    },
    // question 2 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'Inside which HTML tag do we write JS code?',
        choice1: '<script>',
        choice2: '<jscript>',
        choice3: '<scripting>',
        choice4: '<javascript>',
        answer: '1'
    },
    // question 3 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'What is the correct JavaScript syntax to change the content of a <p> 
in HTML document?',
        choice1: 'document.getElement("p").innerHTML = "Hello World"',
        choice2: '(p).innerHTML = "Hello World"',
        choice3: 'getElement("p").value = "Hello World"',
        choice4: 'document("p").innerHTML = "Hello World"',
        answer: '1'
    },
    // question 4 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How would you write "Hello World" in an alert box?',
        choice1: 'msgBox("Hello World");',
        choice2: 'message("Hello World");',
        choice3: 'alertBox("Hello World");',
        choice4: 'alert("Hello World");',
        answer: '4'
    },
    // question 5 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How do you create a function?',
        choice1: 'function:myFunction()',
        choice2: 'function = myFunction()',
        choice3: 'function myFunction()',
        choice4: 'var function.value() = myFunction()',
        answer: '3'
    },
    // question 6 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How do you write an "if" statement?',
        choice1: 'if = i == 5',
        choice2: 'if (i == 5)',
        choice3: 'if i == 5 then',
        choice4: 'if i = 5',
        answer: '2'
    },
    // question 7 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How do you make a comment in JavaScript?',
        choice1: '/*example*/',
        choice2: '<!--example-->',
        choice3: '//example',
        choice4: '`example`',
        answer: '3'
    },
    // question 8 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'What is the correct way to make an array?',
        choice1: 'var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]',
        choice2: 'var colors = ("red", "green", "blue")',
        choice3: 'var colors = {"red", "green", "blue"}',
        choice4: 'var colors = "red", "green", "blue"',
        answer: '1'
    },
    // question 9 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'JavaScript is a ____-side programming language.',
        choice1: 'Client',
        choice2: 'Server',
        choice3: 'Both',
        choice4: 'None',
        answer: '3'
    },
    // question 10 ^^^^
]


//start game functionality and needed var
const SCORE_POINTS = 100;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 10;

startGame = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQustions = [...questions];
    getNewQuestion();
}

//get new question function supplies new q when previous gets answered
getNewQuestion = () => {
    if(availableQustions.length === 0 || questionCounter > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score)

        return window.location.assign('./end.html')
    }

    questionCounter++

    //making random question appear
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQustions.length)
    currentQuestion = availableQustions[questionIndex]
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question
    //was originally choices.array.forEach
    choices.forEach((choice)=> {
        const number = choice.dataset['number'];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
    });

    availableQustions.splice(questionIndex, 1);

    acceptingAnswers = true;
}

choices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (!acceptingAnswers) return

        acceptingAnswers = false
        const selectedChoice = e.target
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number']

        let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 
'incorrect'
        //if answer is correct add 100 to score
        if (classToApply === 'correct') {
            incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS)
        } else {
            //timer time will be subtracted by 10 if question is answered incorrectly
            timerSec -= 10;
        }

        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply)

        setTimeout(() => {
            selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply)
            getNewQuestion();
        }, 1000)
    })
});

//increment score funt and calling start game
incrementScore = num => {
    score +=num
    scoreText.innerText = score
}

startGame();



//timer funct for 90 sec
var timerSec = 90;
var timerText = document.getElementById('time-text')
var timer;

timer = setInterval(function() {
    timerSec--;
    timerText.textContent = timerSec
    //if timer is less than or = to 0 the game will end
    if (timerSec <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        return window.location.assign('./end.html');
    //if there is no available q's and the timer is greater than 0 game will end
    }if (availableQustions === 0 && timerSec > 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        return window.location.assign('./end.html');
        }

},1000)
```

As A reminder; the sections above are not the cause for concern I just want ya'll to e able to go through the full functionality of the app. As it stands thats the only way to create a **mostRecentScore** variable and store it to local. The code below are the HTML of the js files associated with the prolem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Good Job!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="end" class="flex-center flex-column">
            <h1 id="final-score">0</h1>
            <form action="" id="end-form-container">
                <h2 id="end-text">Enter your name below in order to save your score. 
</h2>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Enter your 
name">
                <button class="btn" id="save-score-btn" type="submit" 
onclick="saveHighScore(event)" >Save</button>
            </form>
            <a href="./game.html" class="btn">Play Again?</a>
            <a href="./index.html" class="btn">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
    <script src="./assets/end.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is the highscores section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Highscores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/highscores.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="highscores" class="flex-center flex-column">
                <h1 id="final-score">Leaderboard</h1>
                <ul id="high-scores-list"></ul>
                <a href="./index.html" class="btn">Go Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="./assets/highscores.js"></script>
</html>
```

Now for the part that is causing all of my headaches. This is the **end.js**

```
const username = document.querySelector('#username')
const saveScoreBtn = document.querySelector('#save-score-btn')
const finalScore = document.querySelector('#final-score')
const mostRecentScore = localStorage.getItem('mostRecentScore')
const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highScores')) || []

const MAX_HIGH_SCORES = 1000

finalScore.innerHTML = mostRecentScore


saveHighScore = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const score = {
        score: mostRecentScore,
        name: username.value
    }

    highScores.push(score)

    highScores.sort((a,b) => {
        return b.score - a.score
    })

    highScores.splice(10)

    localStorage.setItem('highScores', JSON.stringify(highScores))
    window.location.assign('./highscores.html')

}
```

And the **highscores.js**

```
const highScoresList = document.querySelector('#high-scores-list')
const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highScores')) || []

highScoresList.innerHTML = highScores.map(score => {
    return `<li class="high-score">${score.name} - ${score.score}</li>`
}).join('')
```

Sorry for the very long explanation for what is hopefully a simple fix. Let me know if any edits are needed or if there is follow up questions I can answer.

Thanks for all the potential help!

Comment: This is too long for anyone to realistically go through.

Comment: I was worried about the length too, but all the pieces are needed to make the unwanted behavior happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tools in chrome to see exactly what your application is doing when the game ends and the final score is supposed to update. You should be able to debug your application and find out where the failure is.

Comment: I will definitely try this, I think ive narrowed it down to the mostRecentScore variable updating after the value has been stored in local